# Are amplifiers with optical in/out truly transparent?

Tags: amplifier, optical

I understand that bad amps introduce distortion and that is bad, but wouldn't the best amp be the one that is most true to the input signal, aside from amplitude amplification of course?

Optical output with a digital input, is this just a pass through with the signal amplified? 
Is there no modification, other than amplitude that happens? 
Can output signal clip? 
Do manufacturers regularly "process" the signal before outputting it?

Comment: This question may as well regard "professional" amplifiers, so it is not off-topic.

Comment: I edited your question to stay on topic with the optical angle. Please raise another question about amplifier qualities in general.